# How to plot several box plots with different colours in one figure?

Tags: r, visualization

You can view the structure of my data (in a .txt file) at this github gist here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b61a2f0fce0c079be31d

I have three levels from the same measurements. This is repeated 10 times.

I want to plot all box plots in one figure with different colors (level 1 being 1 one color, level 2 another color, and level 3 another color)
I have researched other questions and answers but could not find a solution.

the code I use is as follows:

```
headers <- read.table("C:/Users/Desktop/example.txt",sep="\t",nrows=2,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data <- read.table("C:/Users/Desktop/example.txt",sep="\t",dec=",",skip=2)
names(data) <- paste(headers[1,],headers[2,],sep="/")
plot.data <- melt(data)
plot.data$level <- as.factor(gsub("(L|l)evel *([1-3])/[A-Z]*","\\2",plot.data$variable,))
plot.data$name <- as.factor(gsub("(L|l)evel *[1-3]/([A-Z]*)","\\2",plot.data$variable,))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plot.data,aes(x=name,y=value,fill=level)) + geom_boxplot()+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=2008:2010)+labs(fill="Year")
```

Comment: In what sense is off-topic? The question is admittedly somewhat vague, but I was able to produce the desired result, implying that it is no problem to understand what the OP wants. And it is definitely not a debugging question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `ggplot2` solution using your data. The challenge is to bring the data in to a suitable format, which is achieved as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
headers <- read.table("example.txt",sep="\t",nrows=2,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data <- read.table("example.txt",sep="\t",dec=",",skip=2)
names(data) <- paste(headers[1,],headers[2,],sep="/")
plot.data <- melt(data)
plot.data$level <- as.factor(gsub("(L|l)evel *([1-3])/[A-Z ]*","\\2",plot.data$variable))
plot.data$name <- as.factor(gsub("(L|l)evel *[1-3]/([A-Z ]*)","\\2",plot.data$variable))
```

The code starts with readin the headers and the numbers separately. The columns are then labelled by combining the Level and the "word" in capital letters (which I called `name` later). The `melt` command (from the `reshape2` package) is then used to convert the data to long format, as is needed for `ggplot`. Finally, I create a `level` and `name` variable.

Now that the data is ready, the plot is quickly done:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plot.data,aes(x=name,y=value,fill=level)) + geom_boxplot() +
    scale_fill_discrete(labels=2000:2002) + labs(fill="Year")
```

The last line sets the labels that are used in the legend and the legend title. The resulting plot is:

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your comment. but I cannot reproduce your solution  here is what I obtain by your code http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xg8iw&s=8#.VVRi-fmqpBc       I want also to put years instead level 1 , level 2 and level 3. I want to put Year  2000 , 2001 and 2002 instead

Comment: That you don't get the same result as I is due to the fact, that your levels are not what they should be. Do you read in *exactly* the file that you posted with *exactly* my code? I have changed the code and figure according to your comment.

Comment: I found the problem, when I submit the data to the website, it changes the structure, please first open the txt file with xls, they should look like above example, consisting of 18 columns of values

Comment: I can see no difference between the example column that you posted and the text file. If there is a difference, could you tell me where. And again: how do you read the data into R?

Comment: The total code that I use, I posted above , here is the problem shown in this figure http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2wqzck2&s=8#.VVSDQPmqpBc    the problem is that it does not plot the same as yours , the legend shows a lot of NA NA, the colors are different

Comment: So it seems that you are doing exactly the same as I. However, there is something strange in your figure: it looks like you had spaces in the labels on the x-axis. E. g., I have `ANEMAKELIKBEN`, while you have `ANEMAKELI KBEN`. If these character sequences have spaces in your code, then my solution fails. I have adapted my code to work also with the spaces (try it, please), but in case the spaces are wrong, you should edit `example.txt` and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

As with most operations in R, colors are recycled when they the vector of colors is shorter than the number of things to be colored. Try this:

```
df = data.frame(foo=rnorm(10),
                foo2=rnorm(10),
                bar=rnorm(10),
                bat2=rnorm(10))
boxplot(df,col = c('red','blue'))
```

see `?boxplot` for details.

Comment: thanks for your comment but the above solution seems to be very close to what I have been thinking